# Angular material custom css

Tags: javascript, angular, css, sass, angular-material

What i am trying to do is to get the primary color for each theme into a css class like this:

```
.primary-color-app{
    background-color : mat-color($primary, default);
}

.primary-color-dark{
    background-color : mat-color($dark-primary, default);
}

.primary-color-pink{
    background-color : mat-color($pink-primary, default);
}

.primary-color-custom{
    background-color : mat-color($custom-primary, default);
}
```

this compiles in a CSS file without problems. but when I try to access the color through the css class it does not show it.

HTML

```
<section>
    <div class="box primary-color-app">
        App
    </div>

    <div class="box primary-color-dark">
        Dark
    </div>

    <div class="box primary-color-pink">
        Pink
    </div>

    <div class="box primary-color-custom">
        Custom
    </div>
</section>
```

they should be shown here

[image]

Using the browser inspector I realized this

[image]

It says that the value of the property is not valid. Why?

Comment: Please add the relevant part of the **compiled** CSS

Comment: is this happening in other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

If you click on `Computado` in your dev console and searching for `background-color` you can see where is located the background color that override it. You can try to (force) override the `background-color` property using the `!important` rule

```
.primary-color-app{
    background-color : mat-color($primary) !important;
}
```

Read more: [CSS The !important Rule](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp)